# Executing Assembly Code on Windows XP?

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, execute

I'm running a WINXP, and I'm quite curious as to how you run or execute assembly code. Is there some sort of application I need, or do I need to run it from a terminal...?

Comment: You need an **assembler**. It serves a similar function to a compiler for code written in higher-level languages.

Comment: There's always [debug.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491040.aspx) - they still ship that in XP! (though I really wouldn't recommend you use that)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use MASM or NASM:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler

Comment: What's the difference between MASM and NASM?

Comment: Google it? 
NASM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler
MASM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler

Answer (score 2):

I have used [**tasm32**](http://www.mediafire.com/?hprpnxw57jamncw) and [**masm32**](http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm) well.. Masm32 has a good gui so ad recommend that. Both also have debuggers. [**masm32forum**](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?) is a good playground also...

Answer (score 1):

You don't run or execute assembly code. Before it can be executed, it needs to be assembled into an executable (hence the name).

Comment: Hm.. Then how do I assemble it into an executable?

Comment: @Arcym: That depends entirely on what kind of assembly code it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need an assembler that is compatible with your systems architecture.  I use TASM (turbo assembler) for x86.  Then you will also need a linker that will allow you to 'execute' the code.